# SpringBoot App doesn't runs with java -jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot app with the following POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>***</groupId>
<artifactId>iaasservicesportal</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>iaas-services-portal</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <start-class>***.iaasservicesportal.IaasservicesportalApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>***</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/datatables.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <!-- include main.properties -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>

        <!-- exclude everything else from filtering -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Repositorio de releases</name>
        <url>https://nexus.***.corp/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Repositorio de snapshots</name>
        <url>https://nexus.***.corp/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

This is the Main Class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class IaasservicesportalApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IaasservicesportalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The problem is that I can export the project as a WAR file to deploy into a Tomcat Server and It works fine. But I need to create a JAR file and execute that with the `java -jar` command.
When I execute the JAR file with `java -jar` command I get the following errors:

https://gist.github.com/jopse/5fb6833341f3398e00476df7ed1f5c25

I didn't found similar errors here. I found problems like jar command or jar exporting but not these errors

> EDIT: Errors in  gist.github.com instead of as code
>
> EDIT: Added a dependency accidentally deleted

Comment: How are you creating a jar file?

Comment: @M.Deinum `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from the POM.

Comment: No that is the pom. You can have anything in your pom but it wouldn't be the first which expects that when using the eclipse create/export jar function to work in the same way.

Comment: I use `clean package` @M.Deinum

Comment: Add the full exception and not snippets. You have a `system` dependency and that won't be in the jar, so if you expect an oracle datasource (or driver) that won't be available.

Comment: Yes, I have two system dependencies, I've being deleted them accidentally from the post. @M.Deinum

Comment: And as I mentioned, `system` scoped dependencies aren't packaged into a jar file. Hence they will not be on the classpath, hence you get the exception you see here. As types expected to be there aren't (like entity listeners and factory beans).

Comment: @M.Deinum is correct. You expect the Oracle driver to be present in the web server's installation directory. This isn't packaged into the `.jar` - the path is coded into the classpath. When you run your application, this dependency cannot be found.

Comment: There is also the `datatables` dependency which I expect to be the main issue.

Comment: I've added the datatables.jar and ojdbc14.jar in /tmp/iaas/dependencies
And I 've changed the path from `<systemPath>` tag in each dependency.
But It still failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally, I have added theese dependencies to a Nexus server.
I have added that Nexus server to the POM file
Resulting this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>***</groupId>
<artifactId>iaasservicesportal</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>iaas-services-portal</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>***</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <!-- include main.properties -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>

        <!-- exclude everything else from filtering -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>thirdparty</id>
        <name>Repositorio de terceras partes</name>
        <url>https://nexus.ci.***/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Repositorio de releases</name>
        <url>https://nexus.ci.***/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Repositorio de snapshots</name>
        <url>https://nexus.ci.***/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
```